# Historical Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I've been approached with a task that requires "historical" array references.
Not sure if this has a correct name or not.
Here's a quick concept in visual form.

```
[NC] == No change to array value

(v1)        (v2)        (v3)        (v4)    (Result)
[10]    ->  [13]    ->  [12]    ->  [13]        = 13
[5]     ->  [NC]    ->  [54]    ->  [NC]        = 54
[6]     ->  [3]     ->  [61]    ->  [30]        = 30
[7]     ->  [3]     ->  [27]    ->  [3]         = 3
[23]    ->  [NC]    ->  [NC]    ->  [NC]        = 23
[41]    ->  [48]    ->  [4]     ->  [48]        = 48
[12]    ->  [NC]    ->  [2]     ->  [NC]        = 2
```

I need to be able to pull a dataset from a certain array set, for example (psudo code):

```
int[] results1 = arraySet.get(v2);
System.out.println(results1[1]); // Prints 5

int[] results2 = arraySet.get(v4);
System.out.println(results2[1]); // Prints 54
```

I have to store about 20 array sets a second, reaching back for the past 5 seconds.
So, 100 array sets in memory.
Each array set will contain around 200 values; so this will amount to quite a large memory consumption.

**My question to you:**

Is there already a Java implementation to do this, which will allow array values to link back to older versions in the array; or will I have to make do with cloning the whole array, and changing the values I need to change? (Plus suffer a nasty memory drawback)

Comment: 100 arrays of 200 ints each is not all that much memory. Are you on a phone or embedded ?

Comment: I suspect you may have some luck searching on "circular buffers"

Comment: @Thilo - It's running on Android, so phone/tablet. So not much RAM or processing power. Both of which I expect to be an issue here.

Comment: 100x200x4 bytes plus some array overhead amounts to about 100kb. Thats *nothing*, not even on a tablet nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of arrays you need is fixed, so you can preallocate them. Use a counter to designate the current array and cycle through.

You cannot avoid using this memory, but you can avoid constantly re-allocating new arrays. There are some complex data structures that allow you to save the 'unchanged' memory, but for this case, it seems just keeping it all in a fixed number of existing arrays is good enough.

I would always keep the actual values in the arrays, so during update you can just copy the old values and overwrite those that have changed.

If you need to know if current_array[i] changed with respect the old_array[i], you can always make a quick comparison.